# How to remove a specific file in Rails public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, paperclip, public

User in my web app are able to upload file. I use Paperclip to handle file attachment issue. Is there any method if I would like to remove any specific user-uploaded file programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting it should be as simple as setting it to nil

```
# assuming...
has_attached_file :picture

@thing.picture = nil
@thing.save
```

or

```
@thing.update_attribute(:picture, nil)
```

and Paperclip will take care of it for you...

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked in Paperclip Readme and couldn't figure it out before. >.<

Comment: I like to define a delete_thing= method that looks for typical boolean form return values and deletes the photo if what's passed in is true.

def delete_thing=(val) thing = nil if val =~ /true/on/1/; end

Answer (score 36):

Ruby's `File` class has a `delete` method:

```
File.delete(Rails.root + '/foo.jpg')
```

Comment: Hi, John. Is there any way to create a folder?

Comment: i think you need to convert pathname to string like Rails.root.to_s